# how to do fix+fast using quickfix?

Tags: quickfix

I consider to buy this connector:

MICEX FIX/FAST Market Data Adaptor http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/market-data-solutions/micex-fixfast.html

But I don't like propriety software by some reasons and would prefer to replace this connector with QuickFix + DIY code.

100 usec perfomance difference is not critical for me, but I do care about features.

In particular MICEX uses FIX+Fast and referenced connector automatically decodes fast: "Hides FAST functionality from user, automatically applies FAST decoding."

The question is how to do the same with quickfix? Is it good idea at all? How easy would be to implement referenced connector using quickfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at http://code.google.com/p/quickfast/ I have used it and is mostly works but it is not the best library.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe QuickFIX supports FAST. FAST is a complex compression specification for FIX messages, and to implement FAST on top of QuickFIX or any FIX engine in a performing way can be tricky.

You want to choose a FAST engine that can generate *template-decoding source code*, in other words, it reads the template XML file from the exchange and spills out code to parse each template. Done this way it's automatic, easy and crucial for speed as the code generated avoids recursion calls otherwise necessary to parse repeating groups.

Take a look on [CoralFIX](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralfix/) which is an intuitive FIX engine with support for FAST decoding.

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralFIX.

Comment: as for fast i'm currently using MFast it works as you wrote. comparing to free FIX8 what is the advantages of CoralFIX?

Comment: Well, I am biased so you should check for yourself, but we believe it is [faster](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15124/what-would-be-considered-a-good-competitive-throughput-for-a-fix-engine/15138#15138), garbage-free, JIT-friendly and the API is [very intuitive and easy to use](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/07/getting-started-with-coralfix/).